# MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY not working for Android Video Capture

Tags: android, video, android-camera

I am working on application where I am recording video from Camera Intent. On my Samsung mobile `MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` is working and even my allocated memory size also works but same application on my Google Pixel there `MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` is not working and even allocated size of memory is not working with camera intent.

My code is given below:

```
public void takeVideoFromCamera(){

        File mediaFile =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/myvideo.mp4");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        Uri videoUri;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
//            videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", mediaFile);
            videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "i.am.ce.by.murgqcy.provider", mediaFile);
        } else {
            videoUri  = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        }
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 5491520L);//5*1048*1048=5MB
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,45);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
```

Comment: There is no requirement for a camera app to honor those extras. You can *request* them, but you cannot *require* them.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY)
You should change the value of  ***MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY*** from 0 to 1.

0 means low quality

Thus could be the solution  `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to reduce Video Quality as well. With '1' it will work?

Comment: I see, so you want the low quality. Perhaps Google Pixel doesn't have that. It's optional for vendors to support this, I've read about several phones that don't have that.